# Set the value of a column, equal to the column that is not zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

As an output of the code, I'm printing a dataframe that contains some processed information (i.e. a performance report of multiple sales teams, the following example is for illustration purposes)

The report shows performance per quarter of the year, and then calculates the yearly performance of each KPI (this is done over 4 years, but the example underneath shows only 2020 for simplicity)

Each KPI's yearly performance is assumed differently, i.e. some are the sum of each quarter, such as sales. In others it is an informative KPI, such as amount of people in the team, in which case *I want to set the value based the last available column with information*.

Now, imagine that some teams have not reported their info on team members. And this info is only available once they report it, however, sales data is available from the system and gets updated daily.

Columns where there is a sum, are no problem, as the code initially sums all the values in the column. However, I am struggling to set the value of a specific row/column based on the last value available in the columns. i.e. `df.iloc[2, 4] = 6` as this is the value of Q3_2020, since Q4 has not been reported yet. **however** for `df.iloc[1, 4] = 4` the value of Q4 is available and its reported as such.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '2020_Q1': [2, 3, 6, 20, 20],
    '2020_Q2': [2, 3, 6, 20, 20],
    '2020_Q3': [5, 3, 6, 20, 20], 
    '2020_Q4': [5, 4, 6, 20, 20],
    '2021_Q1': [5, 3, 7, 20, 20],
    '2021_Q2': [5, 4, 7, 20, 20],
    '2021_Q3': [5, 4, 0, 20, 20],
}, index = ['People', 'AA', 'BB', 'MM', '$$'])

df
Out[]: 
        2020_Q1  2020_Q2  2020_Q3  2020_Q4  2021_Q1  2021_Q2  2021_Q3
People        2        2        5        5        5        5        5
AA            3        3        3        4        3        4        4
BB            6        6        6        6        7        7        0
MM           20       20       20       20       20       20       20
$$           20       20       20       20       20       20       20
```

Once I generate the report the output should look like this:

```
###### Solution code here ######


Out[]: 
        2020_Q1  2020_Q2  2020_Q3  2020_Q4 2020_Total  2021_Q2    2021_Q3  2021_Total
People        2        2        5        5          5        5          5        5 
AA            3        3        3        4          4        4          4        5
BB            6        6        6        7          7        7          0        7
MM           20       20       20       20         80       30         30       60
$$           20       20       20       20         80       30         40       70
```

So far I've tried multiple approaches, but haven't been able to find the right approach.

Tried with an if elif statement

```
df.loc[['People':'BB'],'2020 Total'] =  df.iloc[[0,2],3]  if df.iloc[[0,2],3]>0 elif df.iloc[[0,2],2] > 0 df.iloc[[0,2],2] ... else df.iloc[[0,2],1]  

Out[]: 
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This approach over a single row works, but not over multiple rows.

**Since I have multiple rows with this kind of needs, and this is part of a big forloop, I'd like to have a one line code or the most compact possible way for doing this operation over multiple defined rows.**

**EDIT** I added the DF code from the answer to clarify and structure better the question for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to define function that computes value at the end of the year and use `pandas.apply` to compute the `2020_Total` column.

Fully reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '2020_Q1': [2, 3, 6, 20, 20],
    '2020_Q2': [2, 3, 6, 20, 20],
    '2020_Q3': [5, 3, 6, 20, 20], 
    '2020_Q4': [5, 4, 0, 20, 20],
}, index = ['People', 'AA', 'BB', 'MM', '$$'])

def compute_end_year_value(row):
    if row.name in ['People', 'AA', 'BB']:
        for val in reversed(row):
            if val > 0:
                return val
        return 0
    return sum(row)

df['2020_Total'] = df.apply(compute_end_year_value, axis = 1)
```

I am not sure how index of your dataframe looks like so you may have to tweak the function a bit. It works like this: for rows with financial data, it computes sum; for rows with other data, it looks at the values from reverse and takes the first one that it greater than 0.

Please note that if you run the function multiple times, it would compute different numbers, as it would include new column `2020_Total` into computation. So make sure you run it only once or tweak the code so that it would not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I had the hunch of defining a function, this was spot on.

Comment: One more thing, can I specify the number of steps to consider in `reversed(row)` ? i tried with `.len(4)`  but it has no attribute. tried `._len_` as well... When the full DF is getting the total columns inserted, i dont want it to iterate over previous year quarters.

Comment: Ok, so, to clarify the question:

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I don't know how exactly your datas looks like. But maybe, if you want to check only last 4 columns, you could do something like `for val in list(reversed(row))[:4]:` . Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, the second message was supposed to clarify it. The actual data looks more like this: I have data for the previous years, and current in progress (i.e. until Q3)


`df_a = pd.DataFrame({
    '2020_Q1': [2, 3, 6, 20, 20],
    '2020_Q2': [2, 3, 6, 20, 20],
    '2020_Q3': [5, 3, 6, 20, 20], 
    '2020_Q4': [5, 4, 6, 20, 20],
    '2021_Q1': [5, 3, 7, 20, 20],
    '2021_Q2': [5, 4, 7, 20, 20],
    '2021_Q3': [5, 4, 0, 20, 20],
}, index = ['People', 'AA', 'BB', 'MM', '$$'])`
I adjusted the def to:  `for val in reversed(row)[:4]: ` but 'reversed' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: I'll update the question for  more clarity,

Comment: That's a bit more tricky, I think it will be possible to solve it with some kind of `Multiindex` dataframe. I'll look into it later.